# React & Fire Base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

im using firebase for my auth page.

when im trying to sign in a user with email and password method to firbase
i get back undefined as result .

cant figure out why. the rest of the methods works well like sign up with email and signin with google.

signInWithEmailAndPass fires the signInWithEmailAndPassword method of firebase. Which should signin the user based on the email and password provided and return the user credentials after the auth process with access token and more. but instead the result i get back from firebase is just "undefiend"

**my firebase file looks like this**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
getAuth,
signInWithPopup,
GoogleAuthProvider,
createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

// fireBase connection settings.
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "xxxxxx",
authDomain: "xxxxx",
projectId: "xxxxx",
storageBucket: "xxxxx",
messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
appId: "xxxxx",
measurementId: "xxxxxx",
};

// fireBase settings
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

googleProvider.setCustomParameters({
prompt: "select_account",
});

export const auth = getAuth();
export const db = getFirestore();

export const createUser = async (userAuth,addInfo={}) => {

const userReff = doc(db, "users", userAuth.uid);
const userSnapShot = await getDoc(userReff);

if(!userSnapShot.exists()){
  const {displayName,email} = userAuth;
  const createdAt = new Date();

try {
  await setDoc(userReff,{
    email,
    displayName,
    createdAt,
    ...addInfo,
  })
  
} catch (error) {
  console.log("ops there was an error",error);
}
}
return userReff;
};

// sign in with google 
export const signInWithGooglePopup = () => {
return signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);

};

export const signInWithEmailAndPass =  async (email,password)=>{

return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);


}


export const authWithCredentials = async (email,password)=>{
if(!email || !password) return;
return await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
}
```

**signin page looks like this**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Auth.styles.scss";
import Button from "../Button/Button.Component";
import { signInWithGooglePopup, createUser,signInWithEmailAndPass } from "../../utilities/firebase/firebase.utilities";
import { faGoogle } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import InputField from "../Input/Input.Component";

const initFormFields = {
  email:"",
  password:"",
}

const Signin = () => {
const [formFields,setFormField] = useState(initFormFields);
const { email, password } = formFields;
const onChanageHandler = (event)=>{
 const { name,value } = event.target;
 setFormField({...formFields,[name]:value})
}

  const logGoogleUser = async () => {
    const { user } = await signInWithGooglePopup();
    createUser(user);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { res } = await signInWithEmailAndPass(email,password) ;
      console.log(res);
    
      
    } catch (error) {
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="form_container">
      <div className="form_warpper">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="signin">
          <InputField
               onChange={onChanageHandler}
            label="מייל"
            autoComplete="off"
            placeholder="אימייל"
            name="email"
            type="text"
            className="form_input"
          />
          <InputField
          onChange={onChanageHandler}
            label="סיסמא"
            placeholder="סיסמא"
            autoComplete="off"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            className="form_input"
          />
          <Button type='button' ButtonType="provider_button" onClick={logGoogleUser} >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} />
            -התחברו עם
          </Button>

          <Button  type="submit"   ButtonType="primary_button">
            התחברות
          </Button>
          <span>
            עדיין לא רשומים? <Link to="/signup">הרשמו כאן</Link>
          </span>
        </form>
        <div className="form_col title_group">
          <h2 className="signin_title">
            התחברות לאיזור
            <br /> האישי
          </h2>
          <p>התחברו לאיזור האישי שלכם, הכל במקום אחד</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signin;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i get back undefined as result"? Please be clear what exactly isn't working the way you expect and what specifically you're observing.  We should be able to duplicate your observations with the information you provide.

Comment: very well, 
signInWithEmailAndPass fires  the signInWithEmailAndPassword method of firebase.   Which should signin the user based on the email and password provided and return the user credentials  after the auth process
with access token and more.
but instead the result i get back from firebase is just "undefiend"

Comment: When you have more information to provide, you should add it to the question by editing it, not by adding a comment. The question should contain everyone someone needs to know to understand how you've debugging this so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code may be the reason why your logs is showing `undefined` when trying to sign in using the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`:

```js
      const { res } = await signInWithEmailAndPass(email,password) ;
      console.log(res);
```

[signInWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#signinwithemailandpassword) returns a Promise<[UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential.md#usercredential_interface)>, UserCredential has the [properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential.md#properties) operationType, providerId, and user. Try changing:

```js
      const { res } = await signInWithEmailAndPass(email,password) ;
      console.log(res);
```

To

```js
      const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPass(email,password) ;
      console.log(user);
```